# Does Semantic UI have an indeterminate progress bar?

Tags: semantic-ui

I tried finding one in the default components, and the closest I found was "A progress bar can show activity" on this page: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/progress.html

Comment: Seems llke there isnt but you can create an `indicating` bar with percentage set to 99%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @AVK. You're right, but it's not very pleasing. I found the way Semantic expects us to do it: they have Loaders: http://semantic-ui.com/elements/loader.html#text-loader . I'm hoping they have more components soon.